# How to flag next 12 rows if the first a particular column in pandas is 1

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with three columns “unique id”, “period“, “flag1”. The dataset to be  is sorted by period and then grouped by unique id and a new flag is to be generated for eg: if flag1 for a particular id in a given month is 0 the flag2 should be flagged as 0. However if the flag1 value is 1 for a particular month then the that month and next 11 month should be flagged as 1 in flag2 column irrespective of any value of flag1 for those 11 months. This loop should continue for each id.
Note: some individual unique id has less than 12 rows and some has more than 12 rows. If the rows is less than 12 it will flag 1 for all the rows and if the rows is more than 12 it will look the value of flag1 on 13th row and flag the flag2 0 or 1 based on flag1 value.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
Id Period Flag1 Flag2(Out)
1 Jan-22   0     0
1 Feb-22   1     1
1 Mar-22   0     1
1 Apr-22   0     1
2 Jan-22   0     0
2 Feb-22   0     0
2 Mar-22   1     1
2 Apr-22   0     1
3 Feb-22   0     0
3 Mar-22   1     1
3 Apr-22   1     1
3 May-22   0     1
3 Jun-22   0     1
3 Jul-22   0     1"""),
                    sep='\s+', engine='python')

New Dataframe

Id Period Flag1 Flag2(Out)
1 Jan-21   0     0
1 Feb-21   1     1
1 Mar-21   0     1
1 Apr-21   0     1
1 May-21   1     1
1 Jun-21   0     1
1 Jul-21   1     1
1 Aug-21   1     1
1 Sep-21   0     1
1 Oct-21   1     1
1 Nov-21   1     1
1 Dec-21   0     1
1 Jan-22   0     1
1 Feb-22   0     0
1 Mar-22   0     0
1 Apr-22   1     1
1 May-22   0     1
1 Jun-22   0     1
1 Jul-22   1     1
1 Aug-22   0     1
1 Sep-22   0     1
1 Oct-22   1     1
1 Nov-22   1     1
1 Dec-22   0     1
1 Jan-23   0     1
1 Feb-23   0     1
1 Mar-23   0     1
1 Apr-23   0     0
1 May-23   0     0
```

Comment: Hey Asit sorry I'm done. You keep on moving the goalposts, I have created answers to three different questions already.

Comment: Nevermind! Thanks Marks..Appreciate your help and patience. Sorry for bothering!! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to compute the flag on time-aware periods:

```
df['period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Period'], format='%b-%y').dt.to_period('M')
out = df.merge(df.groupby('Id').rolling(12, min_periods=1, on='period')
               ['Flag1'].max().rename('Flag2').astype(int),
               on=['Id', 'period']
              )
```

Output:

```
    Id  Period  Flag1  Flag2(Out)   period  Flag2
0    1  Jan-22      0           0  2022-01      0
1    1  Feb-22      1           1  2022-02      1
2    1  Mar-22      0           1  2022-03      1
3    1  Apr-22      0           1  2022-04      1
4    2  Jan-22      0           0  2022-01      0
5    2  Feb-22      0           0  2022-02      0
6    2  Mar-22      1           1  2022-03      1
7    2  Apr-22      0           1  2022-04      1
8    3  Feb-22      0           0  2022-02      0
9    3  Mar-22      1           1  2022-03      1
10   3  Apr-22      1           1  2022-04      1
11   3  May-22      0           1  2022-05      1
12   3  Jun-22      0           1  2022-06      1
13   3  Jul-22      0           1  2022-07      1
```

Comment: it turns out OP wants the year after the first 1 to be the one that counts for Flag2 (it doesn't reset if there is a Flag1 in that year)

Comment: @Mark thanks, then one should indeed use a loop. Why did you remove your answer? I updated your answer with the groupby approach in case you want to undelete it.